# How to reference a summary instead of the original sources?

Tags: citations

I always get confused about this when referencing.

Example:

I am writing the Literature Review of my research on AI. I started with the history of AI.

I am reading a paper submitted by a university student online. The paper talks about Dr Turing's role and the Turing Test.

It also summarizes findings collected from different sources into one sentence. I would like to talk about that summary, rather than having to go back to 3 different sources for the original text. What is the right way to reference this? Is it the student's paper or the three original works?

Thank you,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attributing Second-order Citations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/99090/attributing-second-order-citations)